# if statement with empty block gcc compiler optimization behaviour

Tags: c, debugging, gcc, optimization, mingw

I have this C code

```
char msg[] = "hello";
int expr = some_function_giving_back_integers();
if(expr) {
    _dbFunction(msg);
}
```

where `_dbFunction();` is defined as follow

```
#define DBGFL 1
#define _dbFunction(msg) \
    do { if (DBGFL) {\
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", msg); \
    }} while (0)
```

I've read that the above is a best practice for debugging, since the compiler when compiling with `#define DBGFL 0` deals with `if (0)` by removing the if statement for optimization purposes, and following the same with `do { } while (0)`.

**My question is**: as far as the main code is concerned when the preprocessor substitute `_dbFunction(msg)` with an empty statement, even though `expr` can be both 0 or !=0 at runtime, is the compiler smart enough to remove the whole if and avoid the comparison?

I know I can probably answer myself by looking into the generated assembler code, however, I'm still not used to disassemble executables and I need to understand how to optimize my code since the above is inside a long-running for loop.

Appreciate some answer from C experts.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends on whether `expr` has side effects. If not, any decent optimizer should remove it.

Comment: A good rule of thumb: if you can think of an obvious optimization, they've probably implemented it.

Comment: Even if you're not familiar with assembler, godbolt.org makes this easy. It color-codes the assembler code to show how it corresponds to the C code.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Thanks Barmar for the link, it will be a good starting point for getting familiar with an assembler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiling with `clang -O3`

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc > 1) {
        do {
            if (0) {
                printf("foo");
            }
        } while (0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The generated code is just:

```
main:                                   # @main
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
```

The first line loads `0` into the register used for the return value, the second line returns. The test of `argc` is optimized away.

https://godbolt.org/z/aYE5hc

If the `if` condition has side effects, though, it has to be executed.